# Удаление строк в txt по условию

Tags: python, txt

Имеется txt файл, в нем некие данные(события), каждый пронумерован.

Есть столбец `KMAG`: `Значение` .
Hужно удалить все события `KMAG`<5.5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
file = open("experiment.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    if 'KMAG' in line:
        print(line)
  file.close()
```

Comment: Предоставьте пример входных данных в текстовом формате и свои наработки по решению задачи

Comment: Ваш текстовой файл является выводом конвертирования  какого-то оригинального файла *в более пригодном формате для обработки*. Было бы лучше получить **оригинальный файл** чем излишне трудиться над текстовым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код писал почти в слепую, было б удобнее если бы вы прикладывали текст как текст, а не как картинку. Но что есть, то есть.

По крайней мере, такой код точно работает на данных вида:

```
1
a b c d KMAG e f g
0 1 2 3 6.28 5 6 7
bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla

2
a b c d KMAG e f g
0 1 2 3 5.28 5 6 7
bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla

3
a b c d KMAG e f g
0 1 2 3 7.13 5 6 7
bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla
```

Собственно, код:

```
import collections

filepath = 'text.txt'

new_lines, for_remove = {}, []
with open(filepath) as fp:
    num, ind = 1, -1 
    lines = fp.readlines()
    tmp = ''
    for line in lines:
        try:
            num_ = int(line)
            new_lines[num] = str(num)+'\n'+tmp
            tmp = ''
            num = num_
        except:
            tmp += line
            lspl = line.split()
            if ind > -1:
                if float(lspl[ind]) < 5.5:
                    for_remove.append(num) 
                ind = -1
            if 'KMAG' in lspl:
                fi = lspl.index('KMAG')
                if fi > -1:
                    ind = fi
    new_lines[num] = str(num)+'\n'+tmp

for i in for_remove: #удаление ненужных "данных(событий)" из словаря
    new_lines.pop(i)

od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(new_lines.items()))   #сортировка словаря по ключу (нужно, для того чтобы все "данные(события)" вывелись в том же порядке, что и были, то бишь по возрастанию)
with open(filepath, 'w') as out: 
    for k, v in new_lines.items(): 
        out.write(v)
```

Суть в том, что не нужно удалять неверные строки из файла, нужно записывать только верные.

Comment: Большое спасибо! @dmitry klemenkov